# Is there a faster way to get the colors in a screen-shot?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, screenshot, awtrobot

I have piece of code, and what it does is find the colors of an image (or section of the screen) and if the R G and B color's are greater than 127 it put's a 1 in the corresponding position of a 2D int array. Here is the segment I have now, but it is obviously extremely slow. Is there a better way to do this?

```
private void traceImage(){
    try{
        Robot r = new Robot();
        b = new int[470][338];
        for(int y = 597; y < 597+469; y++)
        {
            for(int x = 570; x < 570+337; x++)
            {
                if(r.getPixelColor(x,y).getRed() > 127 &&
                   r.getPixelColor(x,y).getGreen() > 127 && 
                   r.getPixelColor(x,y).getBlue() > 127)
                {
                    b[y-597][x-570] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    b[y-597][x-570] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.toString());}
}
```

There must be a faster way to do this using the values above. `b` is the int array and it is initialized in this segment. `r` is a robot that I use to find the color of the pixel on the screen. `x` and `y` should be self explanatory.

Thanks Mikera! This is the end result I got based on your answer:

```
private void traceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try{
        Robot r = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = r.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(597,570,470,337));
        b = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
        for(int y=0;y<image.getWidth();y++){
            for(int x=0;x<image.getHeight();x++){
                if(image.getRGB(y,x)==-1){
                    b[y][x]=0;
                }
                else{
                    b[y][x]=1;                 
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.toString());}
}
```

The -1 in the if else statement apparently finds the value of black pixels like I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Robot.createScreenCapture()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) to capture the entire subimage in one go.

Then you will be able to query the individual pixels in the subimage much faster, e.g. using [BufferedImage.getRGB(x,y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB%28int,%20int%29)

Interestingly your specific operation has a very fast bitwise implementation: just do `((rgb & 0x808080) == 0x808080)`